# Update ListView after delete operation

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I am displaying data pulled from the Android OS sqlite database. I am successfully getting the items to delete when I click on them. However I am having an issue refreshing, or updating the listview after the operation.

Below is the code where I delete the contact.

```
deleteBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);
    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Deleted: " + c.getId() + " " + c.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            adapter.deleteContact(c.getId());
            updateList();
        }
    });
```

Below is the updateList() method:

```
public void updateList(){
    myList.refreshDrawableState();
    myList.invalidateViews();
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I included in this method all three ways I tried to refresh but none worked for me. Any idea how I might achieve this?

EDIT: I changed my code thinking this would be the solution but it did not work either:

DbAdapter class delete method():

```
public boolean deleteContact(int rowId){
    getAllContactsList();
    return db.delete(DB_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;

}
```

getAllContactsList():

```
public List<Contact> getAllContactsList(){
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList();

    Cursor c = db.query(DB_TABLE, new String [] {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_FNAME, COLUMN_LNAME}, null, null, null, null, null);

    //loop through cursor rows and add to list
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)));
            contact.setfName(c.getString(1));
            contact.setlName(c.getString(2));
            contactList.add(contact);
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactList;
}public List<Contact> getAllContactsList(){
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList();

    Cursor c = db.query(DB_TABLE, new String [] {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_FNAME, COLUMN_LNAME}, null, null, null, null, null);

    //loop through cursor rows and add to list
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)));
            contact.setfName(c.getString(1));
            contact.setlName(c.getString(2));
            contactList.add(contact);
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactList;
}
```

I thought by getting a new cursor before deleting the contact It would update the list accordingly. Unfortunately It made no difference. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to notify the list's adapter that you have modified the underlying data.

Try using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I was doing that with `this.notifyDataSetChanged()` but it was not making any difference to the list for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

You must requery and and generate new list:

```
public void updateList(){
    clear();
    addAll(contactsDbHelper.getAllContactsList()); //addAll works since 11 API version.
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //need this is you dissabled auto notify
}
```

P.S. You should done this job with using [Content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), but you need manually notify content provider about changes, because `Cursor.requery()` is deprecated since 11 version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have the Database Adapter class, but you're missing the ArrayAdapter class, which is intended to manage the list of items, displayed in your ListView. Take a look at [this example](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429), specifically at the WeatherAdapter.java class.

If I am wrong in my assumptions and the `adapter` object in your code is not a database adapter, but an ArrayAdapter class, try putting `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of this.notifyDataSetChanged().

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: The updatelist() method is a method of a class which extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>.